# accessing object needs setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I haven't encountered this before and searches don't reveal an answer. I have an ajax call that pulls into a javascript object.

```
var order = checkOrder();
console.log("t1: ", order);
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("t2: ", order.responseText);
    console.log("t3: ", order.statusText);
    console.log((order.responseText != '') ? order.responseText : order.statusText);
}, 100);

function checkOrder() {
    return $.get('SCRIPTPATH', function(data) { return data; });
}
```

The odd part i can't figure out isthe first console.log spits out the correct data indicating that "order" is in fact set to the proper oject data but when i try to access the data it is undefined. it's only when i wrap it in a setTimeout function no smaller than 100 that it outputs the proper data for those object values.

Does anyone know why this would happen? again the order variable gets set as the first console.log outputs all the proper data, its only the ones after that try to access the object values that are undefined unless i wrap them in a timeout function.

output in the console (unfolded the object so you can see the data values are there):

```
t1:  {…}
    ​abort: function abort()​
    always: function always()​
    catch: function catch()​
    done: function add()​
    fail: function add()​
    getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()​
    getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader()​
    overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType()​
    pipe: function pipe()​
    progress: function add()​
    promise: function promise()
    ​
    readyState: 4
    ​
    responseText: "OK"
    ​
    setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()​
    state: function state()
    ​
    status: 200
    ​
    statusCode: function statusCode()
    ​
    statusText: "OK"
    ​
    then: function then()​
    <prototype>: Object { … }

t2:  undefined
t3:  undefined
undefined
```

The checkOrder function uses the jQuery $.get() and i checked the rest of the code for ajaxSubmitComplete or something similar and didn't have anything like that. a 1/10 second delay isn't that big of a deal but don't like the idea of having to wrap all the subsequent code in a timeout function.

Based on mgarcia's answer here is updated code that seems to work (OK is the response given from server script on success):

```
checkOrder().then(function(order) {
    if(order == "OK") {
        //proceed with order
    }
    else {
        //something went wrong
    }
});

function checkOrder() {
    return $.get('SCRIPTPATH', function(data) { return data; });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *checkOrder* method returns a promise. You should wait for that promise to resolve:

```
checkOrder().then(function(order) {
    // I'm assuming here that your checkOrder method returns the data once it has resolved so that you have the order object available.
});
```

Comment: Thank you :), this seemed to work best although clunky each time i have to use it

Answer (score 2):

ajax is asynchronous.  You've got a race condition, where set timeout is working (right now) because your ajax is returning before the timeout runs out.  If your server side call took longer it wouldn't work (everythign would still be undefined)

Instead of just returning the data and counting on it being available on the next line, you could write a function that handles the response from the ajax, and pass that to the ajax call.

```
function handleData = function(order) { 
    console.log("t2: ", order.responseText);
    console.log("t3: ", order.statusText);
    console.log((order.responseText != '') ? order.responseText : order.statusText);
}

function checkOrder() {
    return $.get('SCRIPTPATH', handleData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the confusing part. If i'm waiting for something to complete from the server, why is the order variable set with the proper data but trying to access the object values inside that variable undefined? If i'm waiting for something to complete wouldn't the initial order variable be undefined too? Javascript is still top down execution so if the variable has the proper data then subsequent requests to object values within that variable should also be there. Almost as if it sets the variable...deletes the data...then resets the variable once the AJAX completes?